# Make tableView subView scroll with the tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have an imageView as a subView of a tableView that I would like to always be in the background of the tableView even when the tableView is scrolled down. The way I have it now, i'm assuming because the imageView frame is fixed to the tableView frame, when I scroll down the tableView then end of the image is reached and it just shows the background color of the tableView.

My code:

```
        let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: background)
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.bounds.width, view.bounds.height)
        let darkBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: darkBlur)
        blurView.frame = imageView.frame
        imageView.addSubview(blurView)
        self.tableView.insertSubview(imageView, atIndex: 0)
```

Comment: You can add imageview as the back ground of whole screen which alpha <1, and an tableview behind that imageview

Comment: @khuong291 Would I be able to scroll the tableView if it's behind the imageView?

Comment: Ah, sorry. put the image behind the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

It should go like this

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "backgroundImage.png")!)
```